# AWS Lambda NodeJS HTTP Request, print data from API

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

The code below returns "Got response: 301" in Lambda. I've tried this code in php, python, and now Node. Pasting this link into the browser returns JSON data as in this picture.  How do I get the code to print out that same data? I need to end up putting the data into Mongo.  I can get php and python to print the data locally but not in Lambda.

I think it has to do with [the callback() shown here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html#nodejs-prog-model-handler-callback), and I'm trying to implement it.

[image]

```
var http = require('http');
var url = 'http://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo';
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
http.get(url, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

  res.on("data", function(chunk) {
    console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
  });
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
};
```

I updated the code to:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = 'http://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo';
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
http.get(url, function(res) {
        var data = '';
        res.on('data', (chunk) => { data += chunk; }); 
        res.on('end', () => { console.log("BODY: " + data); });
    }).on('error', (e) => { console.log("Got error: " + e.message);});
};
```

And got this response:

```
START RequestId: 19a21615-7d09-11e7-93cc-cb3212ad23c5 Version: $LATEST 2017-08-09T13:46:10.102Z 19a21615-7d09-11e7-93cc-cb3212ad23c5    BODY:  END RequestId: 19a21615-7d09-11e7-93cc-cb3212ad23c5 REPORT RequestId: 19a21615-7d09-11e7-93cc-cb3212ad23c5   Duration: 277.04 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 19 MB
```

Comment: You probably need to send a valid `User-Agent` header, which the browser does for you automatically but Node does not. The PHP and Python libraries you were using may be sending one. There are libraries for Node that will too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The data received in chunks in order to print all the data you need to listen to 'end' event and then to log it. Try to appending the chunks on each data event and when the end event received log all the data.

```
var https = require('https');
var url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo';
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
https.get(url, function(res) {
    var data = '';
    res.on('data', (chunk) => { data += chunk; }); 
    res.on('end', () => { console.log("BODY: " + data); });
    }).on('error', (e) => { console.log("Got error: " + e.message);});
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't show the data. I think it has something to do with being inside the Lambda function. I edited my question to include your code and its output.

Comment: Changing http to https worked for me. Please find my edits in the answer

Comment: You are my hero. I've worked on this for weeks, and it finally works. Thank you.